# CUDA - Transfering CPU variables to GPU __constant__ variables

Tags: cuda, gpu

As anything with CUDA, the most basic things are sometimes the hardest...

So...I just want to copy a variable from the CPU to a GPU's **constant** variable, and I am having a hard time.

This is what i have:

```
__constant__ int contadorlinhasx_d;

int main(){

(...)
int contadorlinhasx=100;
     status=cudaMemcpyToSymbol(contadorlinhasx_d,contadorlinhasx,1*sizeof(int),0,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

And i get this error

```
presortx.cu(222): error: no instance of overloaded function "cudaMemcpyToSymbol" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (int, int, unsigned long, int, cudaMemcpyKind)
```

Could anyone help me? I know it is some stupid error, but I am tired of googling it, and I have spent almost 30 minutes just trying to copy a stupid variable :/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol("contadorlinhasx_d",
                   &contadorlinhasx,
                   1*sizeof(int),
                   0,
                   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

[Note this is the old API call, now deprecated in CUDA 4.0 and newer]

or

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(contadorlinhasx_d,
                   &contadorlinhasx,
                   1*sizeof(int),
                   0,
                   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

If you look at the [API documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g2a229a704ade54887f7784e2e2dbd895), the first two arguments  are  pointers. The first can either be a string, which will force a symbol lookup internally in the API (pre CUDA 4), or a device symbol address (CUDA 4 and later). The second argument is the address of the host source memory for the copy. The compiler error message is pretty explicit - you are passing the wrong types of argument and the compiler can't find an instance in the library which matches.

Comment: Thank you! At one point I had "contadorlinhasx_d" but I forgot the "&" completely. I am really grateful for your help ;)