# in cuda,how can I send an integer to the constant memory?

Tags: cuda

> **Similar Post(but not exactly the same)**
>   [CUDA - Transfering CPU variables to GPU __constant__ variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056934/cuda-transfering-cpu-variables-to-gpu-constant-variables)

In CUDA,I used the code below to copy an integer to the constant memory,but It show me a different number!why?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuPrintf.cu"

__constant__ int num;
__global__ void kernel(int *a,int *k){
cuPrintf("\nnum=%d\n",num);
}
void main(){
 int x;
 printf("Please enter the number you want to find it on array:");
 scanf("&%d",&x);
 cudaMemcpyToSymbol( &num, &x,sizeof(int)*1, 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 int wait;
 scanf("&%d",&wait);
}
```

Comment: If your error message is different to the question linked by @talonmies, then please post more detail.

Comment: I changed my code,but I still have problem with it,it show me a wrong number!